# What is the meaning of "all zero at the bone"? I can't make it out

Tags: meaning, expressions

From *The Shining*, by Stephen King:

> Jack turned back, ***all zero at the bone.***

What is the meaning of this expression?

Comment: Note that it is not an idiom and there is no connection to idioms.

Comment: For a definition of idioms (== a phrase with a well-established, known meaning, even though literally it is meaningless or bizarre) simply click to any dictionary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Zero at the bone* seems to be an idiomatic expression off Emily Dickinson's poem:

> But never met this fellow,
>   Attended or alone,
>   Without a tighter breathing,
>   And **zero at the bone**.

The implication seemingly being a reference Zero (O° F – cold!) to the bone. Literally, a chilling fear!

It's informal and not a set idiom as such.

See also:

> "Zero" suggests cold and also nothingness. That the feeling penetrates to "the bone" suggests how deeply felt, how intense the emotion is. When you put all these details together, does the response sound like fear? ([Melani, Brooklyn College](http://academic.brooklyn.cuny.edu/english/melani/cs6/snake.html))

and

> … there will be a fearful constriction of chest and lungs, and bone marrow temperature will plummet. ([Wood, humanities360](http://www.humanities360.com/index.php/analysis-of-dickinsons-a-narrow-fellow-in-the-grass-52707/))

Comment: You know, (1) it's not in any way an idiom. King was possibly making **an obscure reference** to the poem, and **homage**, or, it is a sheer coincidence. In any event it's not in the slightest an idiom in English, and has nothing to do with idioms.  (2) It's unclear if Dickinson meant **temperature** (for me it would be unusual to use the 'technical' sounding 'zero' in her year of writing); perhaps it more just suggests nothingness, evil blankness.

Comment: Kris - you're absolutely right. But then, literally the first 10 words of your answer, are, confusing/wrong! Heh!

Comment: PS I'm not sure what you mean about book titles (there's one action-thriller (??) series, entitled "Zero at the bone")

Comment: Idiomatic means that the meaning is known (to repeat, **is in fact known**) from common usage, and is **not deducible from the literal words**.  "zero to the bone" is perfectly literal.  whereas something like "brass monkeys!" is an idiom.  it is unclear / ambiguous whether the "zero" means temperature or spirit - but so what?; ambiguities are not idiom and have nothing to do with idiom.  **Note that, critically -- we do not know what the phrase means!** Heh!!! It's not an idiom like "brass monkeys" where, in fact, we know what it means (due to common usage).

Comment: If it is idiomatic, **state the meaning**. It's just that simple. Idiomatic means, the meaning (which cannot be deduced literally) **is established** and well-known by custom, even though the literal meaning is bizarre/dadaist (like "brass monkeys"). This is literally the opposite of an idiom: an obscure phrase where, we all agree, we do not know quite what it means.  (Your comment about "extended discussions" is odd, are you new to these sites? It does not appear so from your points!  This is a SHORT discussion :) )

Answer (score 5):

It's from [Snake](http://www.online-literature.com/dickinson/455/) by Emily Dickinson,

> But never met this fellow,
>   Attended or alone,
>   Without a tighter breathing,
>   And zero at the bone.

It's an allusion to a basic fear (originally of serpents), it is a feeling in your *bones* (or perhaps *soul*).

Comment: I read it as another way of describing the phenomenon in which (to cite a genuine idiom) *one's bones turn to jelly*. (Nothing to do with physical temperature, in other words; rather, the reference is to the fear-inspired metaphorical dissolution of that substance which normally keeps us standing upright and capable of moving our limbs, as you may have been implying. Checking the relevant passage of *The Shining* at Google Books seems to support this interpretation: Jack is made fearful by a remark his son has just uttered.)

Comment: @Erik I think both interpretations are valid. It's poetry.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to mean "chilled to the bone" (not just physically).

"Wanted to meet you, but not so much by accident that you'd be suspicious."

I went zero to the bone.

The first line is spoken by the human guide of an alien visiting earth; the second is the response of the person he addresses. From Rebecca Ore's story *Alien Bootlegger,* collected in Gardner Dozois' "Year's Best Science Fiction, 11th Annual Collection."